# sync automatic background offline

Tags: backup, background, offline

I'm working on some documents on a laptop which is sometimes offline (it runs winXP).
I'd like to backup automatically the documents to a folder to a remote location so that it runs in the background.

I want to edit the documents and forget about backuping and once online - have it all backuped to a remote location, or even better - to an svn server or something that supports versioning.

I want something which is:
1. free
2. does not overload the network too much but only send the diff.
3. works 100%

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

DropBox does everything your asking. http://www.getdropbox.com/

Plus it's fully cross platform, Windows, Mac, Linux.

Free up to 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

I like [IDrive Online](http://www.idrive.com/) personally. It's Windows/Mac (no Linux), 2 GB free, and here's the important bit: **it stores the last 30 revisions of files**. And the history for a file isn't counted against your space either; only the most recent version counts. None of the other free online backup solutions I've seen handle versioning as well. It supports continuous backup too. Oh, and they handle being offline beautifully -- even losing connection in the middle of the backup process doesn't bother it.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox also keeps previous revisions, including of deleted files.